# Play Store After Publish Errors

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, app-store

I have published my app on play store. But there are some bugs. When I solve them on android studio and run the app on my mobile from the android studio, play console counts it as uninstall ? How can I stop it as my uninstall counts are increasing way faster due to this?